# Why doesn't my wireless mouse connect automatically?

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

Every time I want to use my wireless mouse (Apple Magic Mouse) with my Macbook Pro, I need to plug in a USB mouse and "Connect" the mouse manually via the bluetooth menubar widget. Is there anything I can do to make this happen automatically?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you've paired it before, clicking the mouse after turning it on should do it.

Comment: I hadn't tried this until just now - I think a small part of me just didn't believe it could possibly be that simple. Thanks :-)

Comment: Glad I could help! Isn't Apple great like that?

Comment: Well ... it's simple, but it's not very discoverable. I guess I just expected it to work - after all, the green light on my mouse is flashing. I assumed that was a "trying to connect" signal - who would've thought it needed an extra 'kick' to get things going? Not me, obviously!

Comment: OMG. Was this simple? I was so frustrated already. Thanks a lot!

Comment: as I was reading the comments, I was like 'these people are so sarcastic' but it actually worked. lolz! because when i turned it ON i just hover it around and i don't see the cursor moving, so i assumed it's not working. the solution is 'click the mouse'. very helpful! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting/pairing for the first time, use a USB mouse/keyboard + trackpad to do the following:-

1. Turn on your Magic Mouse
2. Go to System Preferences from the Apple Menu
3. Click on Mouse
4. Your device should be able to detect the Magic Mouse
5. Click on Connect
6. Once you see a message "Connected", mouse is ready to use.

If you have connected/paired your mouse with your Macbook/computer before,

1. Turn on Magic Mouse
2. After a 2 sec pause, click and it should work.

Comment: My keyboard would connect automatically after powering on, but the mouse wouldn't. I thought my mouse had some problems. Click to connect wasn't intuitive. Thanks for the tip.